# android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

My code is this when i run this code i am facing exception

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.admin__home, menu);
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_notifications);
LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();
```

Comment: post error log along with question

Answer (score 1):

> android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable

change this

```
LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) item.getIcon();
```

**to this**

```
Drawable icon = (Drawable) item.getIcon();
```